# Magento theme exceptions not working on the category and product pages

Tags: iphone, magento, mobile

I'm trying to make an iphone and ipad version for my magento store.

I followed the following steps to achieve the fallback:

1. Added exceptions for the mobile devices. Navigated to the Magento administrative area -> System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes. Clicked on the Add Exceptions buttons besides the Templates, Skin and Layout labels.
2. Entered the following line in the Matched Expression field:

iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

3. In the Value field entered iphone and saved the changes.

It worked like a charm for all my pages except for the category and product pages. I checked the Category settings under Manage Categories and the design of these pages seems to be handled in the Custom Design tab.

How do I make my exceptions overide this setting?

Answer (score 1):

I Thought the field in custom design had to be populated with one of the themes from the drop down. Apparently you can leave it on --Please Select-- and it will still save without errors.

The exceptions work perfectly know, DOH!